# How to print out 100 decimal places of sqrt(2)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried various techniques but I can't figure out how to print out 100 decimal places of sqrt(2). decimal.Decimal seems to be counteracted by the calculation itself. Any ideas?

```
import decimal
import math

decimal.getcontext().dps = 100   #arbitrary

print(decimal.Decimal(math.sqrt(2)))
```

Comment: Will `sqrt(2)` actually calculate the square root of 2 correct to 100 decimal places, or will you run into floating-point accuracy limitations?

Answer (score 4):

`math.sqrt(2)` returns a *float* value, which doesn't support the precision you are asking for. Use [`Decimal.sqrt()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.sqrt) instead:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, localcontext
>>> with localcontext() as ctx:
...     ctx.prec = 100
...     Decimal(2).sqrt()
... 
Decimal('1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990732478462107038850387534327641573')
```